# matrix column multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

i have a matrix NV but now i want to multiply only the 2nd column by `2`
how should i go about doing this? this is my current code:

```
NV=zeros(10,10);

g1= 1:1:10;

n=2;
for b=1:n
NV(:,b)=10.^(g1/10);

end
```

Comment: This is a very basic matlab question, try to read some tutorials next time, here's a partial list http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/matlab.html

Comment: btw, multiplication of zeros times 2 makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do the following:

```
NV(:,2)= 2*NV(:,2)
```